# How to trace a fix process’s wakeup latency?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, ebpf, ftrace

I want to use ftrace to trace a fix process’s wakeup latency.
But, ftrace will only record the max latency.
And, set_ftrace_pid is useless.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could [runqlat](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/runqlat_example.txt) or one of the other tools from [the bcc repository](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) help?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tool I wrote to trace a fix process’s wakeup latency.

https://gitee.com/openeuler-competition/summer2021-42

This tool supports analyzing the overall scheduling latency of the system through ftrace raw data.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the suggestion added by @Qeole, you can also use the `perf sched` utility to obtain a much detailed trace of a process' wakeup latency. While `ebpf` tools like [runqlat](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/runqlat_example.txt) will give you a much higher level overview, using `perf sched` will help you capture all scheduler events and thereby, observe and inspect the wakeup latencies of a process in much more detail. Note that running `perf sched` to monitor a long-running computationally intensive process, will come with its own issues of overhead.

You first need to run `perf sched record` -

From the man-page,

```
'perf sched record <command>' records the scheduling events of an arbitrary workload.
```

For eg. say you want to trace the wakeup latencies of the command `ls`.

```
sudo perf sched record ls

[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.453 MB perf.data (562 samples) ]
```

You will see that in the same directory where the command was run, a `perf.data` file will be generated. This file will contain all of the raw scheduler events, and the commands below will help to make sense of all these scheduler events.

- You can run `perf sched latency` to obtain per-task latency summaries, including details of the number of context switches per task, average and maximum delay.

```
sudo perf sched latency

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Task                  |   Runtime ms  | Switches | Average delay ms | Maximum delay ms | Maximum delay at       |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  migration/4:35        |      0.000 ms |        1 | avg:    0.003 ms | max:    0.003 ms | max at: 231259.727951 s
  kworker/u16:0-p:6962  |      0.103 ms |       20 | avg:    0.003 ms | max:    0.035 ms | max at: 231259.729314 s
  ls:7118               |      1.752 ms |        1 | avg:    0.003 ms | max:    0.003 ms | max at: 231259.727898 s
  alsa-sink-Gener:3133  |      0.000 ms |        1 | avg:    0.003 ms | max:    0.003 ms | max at: 231259.729321 s
  Timer:5229            |      0.035 ms |        1 | avg:    0.002 ms | max:    0.002 ms | max at: 231259.729625 s
  AudioIP~ent RPC:7597  |      0.040 ms |        1 | avg:    0.002 ms | max:    0.002 ms | max at: 231259.729698 s
  MediaTimer #1:7075    |      0.025 ms |        1 | avg:    0.002 ms | max:    0.002 ms | max at: 231259.729651 s
  gnome-terminal-:4989  |      0.254 ms |       24 | avg:    0.001 ms | max:    0.003 ms | max at: 231259.729358 s
  MediaPl~back #3:7098  |      0.034 ms |        1 | avg:    0.001 ms | max:    0.001 ms | max at: 231259.729670 s
  kworker/u16:2-p:5987  |      0.144 ms |       32 | avg:    0.001 ms | max:    0.002 ms | max at: 231259.729193 s
  perf:7114             |      3.503 ms |        1 | avg:    0.001 ms | max:    0.001 ms | max at: 231259.729656 s
  kworker/u16:1-p:7112  |      0.184 ms |       52 | avg:    0.001 ms | max:    0.001 ms | max at: 231259.729201 s
  chrome:5713           |      0.067 ms |        1 | avg:    0.000 ms | max:    0.000 ms | max at:      0.000000 s
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TOTAL:                |      6.141 ms |      137 |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

You can see the process `ls`, as well as the process `perf` being present among all the other processes that co-existed at the same time while the `perf sched record` command was being run.

- You can run `perf sched timehist` to obtain a detailed summary of the individual scheduler events.

```
sudo perf sched timehist

           time    cpu  task name                       wait time  sch delay   run time
                        [tid/pid]                          (msec)     (msec)     (msec)
--------------- ------  ------------------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------
  231259.726350 [0005]  <idle>                              0.000      0.000      0.000 
  231259.726465 [0005]  chrome[5713]                        0.000      0.000      0.114 
  231259.727447 [0005]  <idle>                              0.114      0.000      0.981 
  231259.727513 [0005]  chrome[5713]                        0.981      0.000      0.066 
  231259.727898 [0004]  <idle>                              0.000      0.000      0.000 
  231259.727951 [0004]  perf[7118]                          0.000      0.002      0.052 
  231259.727958 [0002]  perf[7114]                          0.000      0.000      0.000 
  231259.727960 [0000]  <idle>                              0.000      0.000      0.000 
  231259.727964 [0004]  migration/4[35]                     0.000      0.002      0.013 
  231259.729193 [0006]  <idle>                              0.000      0.000      0.000 
  231259.729201 [0002]  <idle>                              0.000      0.000      1.242 
  231259.729201 [0003]  <idle>                              0.000      0.000      0.000   231259.729216 [0002]  kworker/u16:1-p[7112]               0.006      0.001      0.005 
  231259.729219 [0002]  <idle>                              0.005      0.000      0.002 
  231259.729222 [0002]  kworker/u16:1-p[7112]               0.002      0.000      0.002 
  231259.729222 [0006]  <idle>                              0.001      0.000      0.007
```

The `wait time` refers to the time the task was waiting to be woken up, and the `sch delay` is the time it took for the scheduler to actually schedule it into the run queue after the task was woken up.

You can filter the timehist command by `pid` and since the `pid` of the `ls` command was **7118** (you can observe this in the `perf sched latency` output).

```
sudo perf sched timehist -p 7118
Samples do not have callchains.
           time    cpu  task name                       wait time  sch delay   run time
                        [tid/pid]                          (msec)     (msec)     (msec)
--------------- ------  ------------------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------
  231259.727951 [0004]  perf[7118]                          0.000      0.002      0.052 
  231259.729657 [0000]  ls[7118]                            0.009      0.000      1.697
```

Now, in order to observe the **wakeup events** for this process, you can run add a command line switch `-w` to the previous command -

```
sudo perf sched timehist -p 7118 -w
Samples do not have callchains.
           time    cpu  task name                       wait time  sch delay   run time
                        [tid/pid]                          (msec)     (msec)     (msec)
--------------- ------  ------------------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------
  231259.727895 [0002]  perf[7114]                                                       awakened: perf[7118]
  231259.727948 [0004]  perf[7118]                                                       awakened: migration/4[35]
  231259.727951 [0004]  perf[7118]                          0.000      0.002      0.052                                 
  231259.729190 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729199 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729207 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729209 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729212 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729218 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729221 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729223 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729226 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729231 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729233 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729237 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729240 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729242 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]

--------------------------------------    # some other events here

  231259.729548 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:0-p[6962]
  231259.729553 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729555 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:0-p[6962]
  231259.729557 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729562 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:0-p[6962]
  231259.729564 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729655 [0000]  ls[7118]                                                         awakened: perf[7114]
  231259.729657 [0000]  ls[7118]                            0.009      0.000      1.697
```

The `kworker` threads interrupt the initial execution of `perf` and its child process `ls` at **231259.729190 ms**. You can see that the `perf` process gets woken up eventually, to be actually executed at **231259.729655 ms** after all of the kernel worker threads have done some work.  You can get a more detailed CPU visualization of the above `timehist` details using the below command -

```
sudo perf sched timehist -p 7118 -wV
Samples do not have callchains.

           time    cpu  012345678  task name                       wait time  sch delay   run time
                                   [tid/pid]                          (msec)     (msec)     (msec)
--------------- ------  ---------  ------------------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------
  231259.727895 [0002]             perf[7114]                                                       awakened: perf[7118]
  231259.727948 [0004]             perf[7118]                                                       awakened: migration/4[35]
  231259.727951 [0004]      s      perf[7118]                          0.000      0.002      0.052                                 
  231259.729190 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729199 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729207 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]
  231259.729209 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729212 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:2-p[5987]

--------------------------------------------------  # some other events here

  231259.729562 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:0-p[6962]
  231259.729564 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: kworker/u16:1-p[7112]
  231259.729655 [0000]             ls[7118]                                                         awakened: perf[7114]
  231259.729657 [0000]  s          ls[7118]                            0.009      0.000      1.697
```

The CPU visualization column ("012345678") has "s" for context-switch events, which indicates that first, **CPU 4** and then, **CPU 0** was context switching to the `ls` process.

**Note** : You can supplement the above information with outputs from the remaining commands of `perf sched`, namely `perf sched script` and `perf sched map`.